# Do I need to list everyone travelling on the UK online visa application?

Tags: visas, uk

I am filling out a UK visa application form to attend a graduation ceremony. I am travelling with 4 friends who are also applying for visas. Do I need to give everyone's information in the "Are you travelling with anyone?" section?

Also, we have booked an apartment which can accommodate up to 6 guests; the booking is in my name. Can my friends submit the same booking confirmation with their applications? Their names do appear on the booking paper as guests.

Comment: You need to go back and read the official guidance more carefully. Specifically the big about which documents you should **not** be including.

Comment: Why?  It's a legitimate question on the form with a legitimate purpose and should be answered with candour and sobriety just like EVERYTHING on an application. It's not clear to me why this should even be a question.  Indeed, what prompts your question?  You need to give more info about it. For your 2nd question, the designated primary should submit and you should reference his GWF number.  Close voting as 'unclear' because we cannot go through this for the 100+ questions on the form. Please explain. Thanks.